# Не подключается Python к vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

У меня такая проблема. Я не могу подключить Python к visual studio code.  он не может выбрать интерпретатор. Хотя python в переменных path указан. Я уже и переустанавливал vs code (полное удаление), и переустанавливал python разных версий. Ничего не помогает. в developer tools пишет ([image: введите сюда описание изображения]на фото)
в output python пишет (на фото)
текущая версия python 3.8.5
Пересмотрел все форумы, ничего не нашел. Помогите, пожалуйста!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну так покажите достопочтенной публике, что за путь у вас прописан в конфигурации, на который вам жалуется ВС во всех ипостасях. А то вряд ли штатная Ванга сможет помочь.

Comment: @void  c:\\Program Files\\Python\\python.exe     но я уже говорил, что я много раз перестанавливал python, и поэтому менялись пути. Но python код работает из командной строки. И кстати, если создать файл task.json  то код тоже выполняется.

Comment: Select Python Interpreter нажимали?

Comment: @void Да нажимал. Проблема заключается в версии интерпритатора. Если установить плагин python в vs code например годовалой версии, то работает. Но если обновить плагин до последней версии в vs code, то проблема возвращается